# How to pass the request-timeout from helm to kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubectl

I'm trying to use helm to deploy applications to kubernetes. In some situations, e.g. working behind proxy, I have to encounter kubectl timeout issue frequently. I can specify --request-timeout when I use kubectl without helm. 
How can I pass --request-timeout from helm to kubectl? thanks.

Comment: Have you considered running a helm pod inside the cluster and use `kubectl --request-timeout` to execute helm commands?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify timeout for install and upgrade using two parameters `--wait` and `--timeout` (check helm install options https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_install/#options). For example

```
helm install --wait --timeout 30 demo ./demo
```

Comment: Looks like this is not working in my env while kubectl --request-timeout  is working for me. however timeout issue might vary depending on system, networking env etc.

Comment: for helm3 you need to specify units, --timeout 10m for ten minutes